# Cannot install Plugin using npm

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I am developing a project using Phonegap/Cordova version 5.4.1.

I have already created a project named "UnishKuri". Now I want to add some plugins, for example: Camera, Splash Screens.

The command that I have used is as follows:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

but I am getting an error with the message

```
"Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-camera via registry.    
 Probably this is either a connection problem , or plugin spec is 
 incorrect. Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL". 
 Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443.
```

I do have proper internet connection. Please do help me out. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: See if this works instead: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git`. This should pull it directly from the repository rather than the registry.

Comment: No I tried that also...It didn't work as well.

Comment: Check your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its a error with the cordova version. Try downgrading your cordova version to 5.1.1 and try again, to see if this is the problem.

```
npm i cordova@5.1.1
```

Then try again to fetch the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

If this works, downgrade your cordova version, or use @matthijs solution:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera.git
```

Comment: Thanks Del, tell me one thing apart from downgrading cordova , do I have to downgrade phonegap(the latest version is 5.4.4)also, as I have created my project using phonegap command.

Comment: You are using both? You should use only one, cordova or phonegap. Maybe this is the error

Comment: okay but whenever I am trying to use any plugin, all the commands for installing any plugins are in cordova....

Comment: I dont know, as I only use cordova. Sorry

Comment: I guess it's a proxy issue... let me clarify that first and then I will give you the update Del